# Fluentd source log format regex

Tags: regex, fluent

Good day!
I have logs of this format:

```
[14-10-2016 00:00:04,004  INFO WebService:1603] [172.16.1.10] [0000077000013] [ID=N0000077000013] [N=147639237688] REQUEST getStatus
```

I came up to this regex:

```
 /(?<time>\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3}) (?<message1>[=]+) .(?<ID>ID=\w*) .(?<N>N=\w*) (?<messages>.*)/
```

I want to identify date, part from INFO till ID=, ID, N, and last part, but fluentd returns me "pattern not match". Each part of regex is working separately on fluentular regex testing site.

What would be a regex?
Thank you.

Comment: Try `(?<time>\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4} +\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3}) +(?<message1>[A-Z]+) .*\[ID=(?<ID>\w+)] +\[N=(?<N>\w+)] (?<messages>.*)`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<time>\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4} +\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3}) +(?<message1>[A-Z]+) .*\[ID=(?<ID>\w+)] +\[N=(?<N>\w+)] (?<messages>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0v7otL/1)

Note that I added `+` after the spaces to match 1 or more occurrences, and adjusted group boundaries for `ID` and `N` groups.

Also, your `message1` group pattern `[=]+` matches 1+ `=` symbols, while you have `INFO` string there. I changed it to `[A-Z]+` to match 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters.

And finally, since there is text between group `message1` and `ID`, you need to make sure to consume those characters, thus, I used `.*` (any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols).